# Laravel Jetstream Custom Authentication Login Process Pass Request

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-jetstream

I've been reading and following [jetstream's documentation](https://jetstream.laravel.com/2.x/features/authentication.html#customizing-user-authentication) and I wanted to create a custom class for the authentication process:

> If you prefer to encapsulate your custom authentication process within
> a class instead of a closure, you may pass a PHP "callable" array to
> the authenticateUsing method:
>
> ```
> use App\Actions\AuthenticateLoginAttempt;
> use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
>
> Fortify::authenticateUsing([new AuthenticateLoginAttempt, '__invoke']);
> ```

I have already created the file AuthenticateLoginAttempt in App/Actions folder:

```
<?php

namespace App\Actions;

class AuthenticateLoginAttempt
{
    public function __invoke()
    {

    }
}
```

What I wanted is also to pass the Request $request as an argument that will be used later in the __invoke magic method:

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing([new AuthenticateLoginAttempt, '__invoke', ...Request $request...]);

public function __invoke(Request $request)
{
    
}
```

How to achieve this one? It seems to me that their documentation is unclear to me. Thank you.